# Array sort not working, no instance(s) of variable(s) T exist so that Employee conforms to Comparable

Tags: java, arrays, list

I created this program. I'm trying to get it to sort my list, but it will not sort. I have included the main program as well as my Employee class.

t spits out this when I try to sort it:

> sort(java.util.list)            in Collections cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList )

Here is the error code I am given :  no instance(s) of variable(s) T exist so that `Employee` conforms to `Comparable<? super T>`

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Employee {
    String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Used to print student details in main()

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}


public class Schedule {
    public static void main (String args[] ) {

        ArrayList<Employee> listOfEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        listOfEmployees.add(new Employee("Lauren"));
        listOfEmployees.add(new Employee("Greg"));
        listOfEmployees.add(new Employee("Brenda"));
        listOfEmployees.add(new Employee("Derek"));
        listOfEmployees.add(new Employee("Brittany"));

        System.out.println("Unsorted");


        for (int i=0; i<listOfEmployees.size(); i++) {

            System.out.println(listOfEmployees.get(i));
        }

        Collections.sort(listOfEmployees);

        System.out.println("Sorted Alphabetically");

        for (int i=0; i<listOfEmployees.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(listOfEmployees.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to tell how the comparison should occur between two instances of `Employee` (maybe this can help you [Java Comparable](https://www.javatpoint.com/Comparable-interface-in-collection-framework))

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7):

You need to implement `Comparable` interface and override its `compareTo` method like following:

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee employee) {
        return this.name.compareTo(employee.name);
    }
}
```

And if you don't want to implement `Comparable` interface then you have to create a custom `Comparator` like follwing:

```
Comparator<Employee> employeeNameComarator = new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee employee1, Employee employee2) {
        return employee1.name.compareTo(employee2.name);
    }
};
```

And the pass the comparator object while sorting like:

```
Collections.sort(listOfEmployees, employeeNameComarator);
```

Comment: If you want to sort at runtime using any other property, you can consider using `Comparator` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Comparator`.

```
listOfEmployees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the Comparable interface in order to use Collections.sort().
Please go through below oracle docs for more information:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)